# Why Poisson probability P(X < λ) is greater than P(X > λ)?

Tags: probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

I can intuitively grasp, why Poisson distribution is not symmetric. As I understand, because it is limited by zero, probabilities on the left side from its mean ($λ$) are being "thickened". But why sums of probabilities on both sides from the mean are not equal?

For example, with $λ=1.5$, Poisson probability of $P(X < λ)$ would be $0.55783$. But shouldn't there be equal probabilities of getting more and less than $1.5$ event's occurrences? And does this difference repeat with examples of data from the real world or it is just some kind of inaccuracy of Poisson distribution?

Comment: Why should $P(x<\lambda)=P(x>\lambda)$? In the real world, almost everyone has more than the mean number of legs.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I agree with you, but if mean number of legs had been $1.5$ and we had been making a distribution of probabilities of having certain numbers of legs, it would have been quiet natural to assume that probabilities of having $1$ and  $2$ legs are equal.
Of course, in a single population there would be more people with either 1 or 2 legs, but if we had inspected a big enough number of populations, our distribution could have been right.

Comment: Actually, I didn't meant to say, that I am 100% sure that $P(x<λ)$ should be equal to $P(x>λ)$. I am mostly interested if there is a reason why exactly $P(x<λ) > P(x>λ)$ and not vice versa, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a continuous distribution, it is the **median** (not the mean) that satisfies the equation:

$$\mathbb{P}(X < x_\text{median}) = \mathbb{P}(X > x_\text{median}).$$

This does not hold exactly for a discrete distribution, owing to the fact that there is positive probability at the point $x_\text{median}$, but still, it should hold approximately.  Now, the Poisson distribution is a positively skewed distribution, and its mean is higher than its median.  Thus, the result you are observing is quite unsurprising.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've additionally explored some materials about derivation of Poisson distribution formula and now the issue described in my question doesn't seem like some mistake in it for me, even though I wouldn't presume such behavior of the distribution intuitively.

Comment: That property will generally (but not always) hold for distributions with mean higher than their median --e.g., positively skewed distributions.

Answer (score 1):

Your assertion is correct for integer $\lambda$ because of the skewness of the Poisson distribution.

But it is not correct for all positive real $\lambda$, and in a handwaving sense, you might say your assertion is only correct for two-thirds of possible $\lambda$.

For example with $\lambda = 1.8$ you get $P(X < 1.8) \approx 0.463$ and $P(X > 1.8) \approx 0.537$, so the reverse of your assertion.

This reversal happens for some values between every pair of integers and the interval in which it occurs gets slightly wider as the integers get larger, initially for $\lambda \in (\log_e(2),1)$ i.e. about $(0.69315,1)$,  and as integer $n$ becomes larger then the interval approaches $(n-\frac13,n)$ such as $\lambda \in (6.67,7)$.